# Calculate the value of  when the two graphs intersect

Tags: systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-functions

**Question:**

> In the graph given:
>
> The solid curve is the graph of $ = 2.cosh (\frac{}{2}$)
>
> and the dotted line is $ = 8x$
>
> a) Calculate the value of  when the two graphs intersect, correct to 4 .significant figures.
>
> b) Hence calculate the area of the shaded region

So i'm to solve simultanious equations to find the two intersects on the graph.

Can anyone show me how to solve these  please?

$2.cosh (\frac{}{2}) = 8x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cosh \frac {x}{2} = 4$$ $$\implies \frac {e^\frac {x}{2} + e^{-\frac {x}{2}}}{2} = 4$$ $$\frac {e^x +1}{e^\frac {x}{2}} = 8$$ $$e^x -8e^\frac {x}{2} + 1 = 0$$ Let $e^\frac {x}{2} = u $. Then our equation becomes  $$u^2-8u + 1 = 0$$

Can you solve the quadratic equation and simplify?

Comment: Other than $x = 0$, of course.

Comment: I can follow up the the part where the 'u's come into it, and using the quadratic formula?

Comment: @PMA Solve for $u $. Choose the non negative solution. Then use $x = 2 \ln u $.

Comment: Can you show the steps to get to $\frac {e^x +1}{e^\frac {x}{2}} = 8$ please?

Comment: I would have wrote it as $ e^\frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{e^\frac {x}{2}} = 8$ but thats not the same is it?

Comment: @PMA Both steps are same. Just cross multiply, that is, $$e^{\frac {x}{2}} + \frac {1}{e^{\frac {x}{2}}} = \frac {e^\frac {x}{2} \times e^\frac {x}{2}}{e^\frac {x}{2}} + \frac {1}{e^\frac {x}{2}} = \frac {e^x + 1}{e^\frac {x}{2}} $$